# Get drupal user session in Yii subdomain

Tags: php, session, drupal, yii, drupal-7

I have two sites, one is parent site **www.example.com** (which is developed in drupal) and other site is subdomain, let say **app.example.com** (which is in Yii )
Now user logged-in using drupal site and once it logged-in, and it can visit app.example.com , I need detail of user in yii .

Currently,
Yii::app()->user->isDrupalAuthenticated() always returns false even if user is logged in.

*before creating subdomain, I was accessing yii site using www.example.com/app which is working fine. But now its creating problem

I have this code in yii:-

```
class LoginController extends Controller {
    public $defaultAction = 'initialize';

    public function actionInitialize() {
                   $this->verifyDrupalUserIdentity();
    }

    private function verifyDrupalUserIdentity() {
                    new DrupalUserIdentity();
                    if (!Yii::app()->user->isDrupalAuthenticated()) {// check if user logged in
                              header('refresh:5;url=http://www.example.com');
                              Yii::app()->end();
                              exit;
                    }
          }

}



define('DRUPAL_ROOT', '/var/www/example');
define('BASE_URL', 'http://www.example.com/');

class DrupalUserIdentity extends CUserIdentity {
          /**
           * Overriding the default constructor inherited from CUserIdentity
           */
          public function __construct() {
                    $this->authenticate();
          }        
          public function authenticate() {

                    global $base_url;
                    $base_url = BASE_URL';
                    $currentPath = getcwd();
                    require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
                    require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/errors.inc';
                    drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
                    chdir($currentPath);

                    global $user;
                    $this->username = $user->name;
                    $this->_id = $user->uid;
                    new DrupalUser();
                    Yii::app()->user->setDrupalAttributes($user);
          }



}


class DrupalUser extends CWebUser {

          private $_attributes;

          public function setDrupalAttributes($attributes) {
                    $this->_attributes = $attributes;
          }


          public function getDrupalAttribute($att) {
                    if ($this->_attributes->$att) {
                              return $this->_attributes->$att;
                    }
          }


          public function isDrupalAuthenticated() {
                    if ($this->_attributes->uid > 0) {
                              return true;
                    }else
                              return false;
          }

      public function getId() {
                    return $this->_attributes->uid;
          }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i have solved this issue by enabling a line in drupal settings file

```
$cookie_domain = '.example.com';
```

now i can access drupal session in my yii domain